# SharePoint Online - Filter Category missing when adding web parts

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, filter

When I am trying to add web parts(filter category) in SharePoint Online 2013 I did not find the filter category. I have searched about this and activated SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Features but still found missing. Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to activate `SharePoint Server Enterprise Site collection features`(the one at Site collection level).

Go to site settings > Site collection features and activate it.

[image]

Comment: Yes..I am only activated the feature in Site Level. Thank You.

Comment: @Gautam Sheth I have activated this feature both on site and site collection level. Also tried deactivating and reactivating these features. But, I am not able to find the "Filters" web parts

Comment: strange, looks like it has changed. What plan do have in SPO ? I guess they are only available in some plans

Comment: is it available for E3 plan?

Comment: @GaneshSanap it is indeed supported in E3 plan, not sure why its not working at your end. Can you try it another site collection, maybe of a different template ?

Answer (score 2):

Filter web parts are part of SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise Edition, It is included in Enterprise feature. Which SP 2013 online license you are using ?

Comment: SharePoint Online (Plan 2)

Comment: Plan 2 has enterprise features. as mentioned in https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans....it should work..what site collection template is being used?

Comment: Publishing Site