# Filter a Library and multiple Lists on a Page based on the same column (date)

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, sharepoint-list-filter, connection-filters

In classic mode a List Filter Web Part is available but what to do in a modern site. Is it still possible to use a classic page in a modern site with the List Filter Web Part? If yes how if no, is there an other way?

To use a classic page in a Modern site I found 
[How to bypass the new Modern Team Site Page experience](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-bypass-the-new-modern-team-site-page-experience/).

To use a List Filter Web Part I read at [Connect a Filter Web Part to a List View Web Part on a classic page](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-on-a-classic-page-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f?ocmsassetID=HA010250989&CorrelationId=850a38b4-541c-4c06-aa66-3785530925e6&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB#BMs1).

But the Filter Web Part is not available in the categories on the classic page.
Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the **Filters** section in web part you need to activate the **`SharePoint Server Enterprise Site collection features`** at site collection level.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to your Site collection.
2. Go to Site collection settings. its URL will be like `siteUrl/_layouts/15/settings.aspx`.
3. Select **Site collection features** under **Site Collection Administration** section. its URL will be like `siteUrl/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site`.
4. Search for **SharePoint Server Enterprise Site collection features** and then click **Activate**.

Comment: Have you activated it at **site collection level**? Can you please refresh page (if you have not) and then try adding web part on classic page.

Comment: I have made a new page and now I can configure it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote ( ^ ) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that other users can find the correct answers easily.

Answer (score 0):

Do as Ganesh said.

Similar issue post for your reference:

[SharePoint Online - Filter Category missing when adding web parts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200396/sharepoint-online-filter-category-missing-when-adding-web-parts)